# JSF SelectOneMenu not working without converter?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, xhtml, converters

So I have the following xhtml code:

```
<p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{interview.interviewer.name}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{interview.interviewer}" style="width:100%" converter="interviewerConverter">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{interviewerController.allInterviewers}" var="s" itemLabel="#{s.name}" itemValue="#{s}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
        </f:facet>
</p:cellEditor>
```

When I try to edit the data in the cell, I get the following error:

```
Conversion Error setting value 'com.jpa.entities.Interviewer@288002c2' for 'null Converter'.
```

I took a look at the similar posts but did not find out what is wrong here.

Also I have created the following converter, **with this I do not get a converter error**:

```
@FacesConverter("interviewerConverter")
public class InterviewerConverter implements Converter {

public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
    if(value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
        try {
            InterviewerController service = (InterviewerController) fc.getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("interviewerController");
            return service.getallInterviewers().get(Integer.parseInt(value));
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid"));
        }
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}

public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {
    if(object != null) {
        return String.valueOf(((Interviewer) object).getId());
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

**After implementing the converter, I get a NullPointerException on the following list:** (service.getallInterviewers())

```
 return service.getallInterviewers().get(Integer.parseInt(value));
```

but in the controller, the list is initialized like this:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    initAllInterviewers();
}
```

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Does it work when not using a celleditor/datatable? Does it work with a plain jsf `h:selectOneMenu`? And please post version and implementation info of jsf

Comment: After I created the converter I do not get a converter error, but I get a NullPointerException on a list (in the converter function). I edited the post with the details.

Comment: Ahhhh ok, then it is not PrimeFaces or xhtml related. Please also add version info.

Comment: And are you sure the `interviewerController` is application scoped?

Comment: The interviewerController is RequestedScoped. Do you think it would work with the ApplicationScoped annotation?

Comment: No idea but it should match the way you retrieve it. If you use jsf 2.3 you can use injection. Or try omnifaces

Comment: jsf version is 2.2. Tried with ApplicationScoped, but did not work, I still get the NullPointerException.

Comment: Well now I tried omnifaces and it looks like it works fine with that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Side note: you should not accept/offer entity ID numbers from/to the potentially evil user.

Comment: if you specify `converter="interviewerConverter"` on the SelectOneMenu - the converter needs to exist. So, it obviously only works after adding your `@FacesConverter("interviewerConverter")`... ? (So, what's your exact problem?)